# Continuity equation for flat Universe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, space-expansion

I have a trouble with question that states:

> Suppose that the Universe is spatially flat and, at some stage of its evolution, is dominated by a fluid with a so-called 'stiff' equation of state: $p=\rho c^2$.
>
> a) Solve the continuity equation for $\rho$ and obtain the scaling of
>   $\rho$ with respect to the scale factor $a.$
>
> b) Use the above result and solve the Friedmann equation to get the
>   temporal dependence of the scale factor $a=a(t)$, assuming a spatially
>   flat Universe and taking the initial conditions to be $a(t=0)=0$.
>
> c) Once you know $a(t)$ calculate the Hubble parameter $H(t)$ and the
>   density $\rho (t)$ as functions of time.
>
> d) What is the value of the barotropic parameter $w$ for such a fluid?

Relevant equations:

Continuity equation: $\dot{\rho}+3H(\rho+\frac{p}{c^2})=0$

Friedmann equation for flat Universe: $H^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho$

Hubble parameter: $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$

However, I am stuck at the first task, as I get $\dot{\rho}+6H\rho=0$ and I am not sure what to do next. How should I scale the $\rho$ with respect to $a$? How to get rid of derivative of $\rho$ without solving it for $\rho(t)$ (as it's part of d) point)?

Comment: Substitute $\rho$ or H from second equation to get an eqthe for one or the other. Then get the other, or substitute H for the a's and you get an equation for the a's. You have enough equations to so,ve for anything.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).